# How to compare two maps

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, comparison, vba

I have a few maps in a workbook and am wondering whether there is a way to  compare the specific characters that are in the same position in two maps.

For example, I have a map looking like this on sheet 1:

```
   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J 
1: @   @   @   @   @   @   Z   @   @   @
2: @   @   Z   @   @   @   @   @   @   @
3: @   @   @   @   @   @   Z   @   Z   @
4: @   @   @   @   Z   @   @   @   @   @
5: @   Z   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @
6: @   @   @   @   @   @   @   Z   Z   @
7: @   Z   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @
8: @   @   @   @   @   @   Z   @   @   @
9: Z   @   @   @   Z   @   @   @   @   @
```

Another map on sheet 2 looks like this:

```
   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J 
1: @   @   @   @   @   @   Z   @   @   @
2: @   @   Z   @   @   @   @   @   @   @
3: z   @   @   @   @   @   Z   @   Z   @
4: @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @
5: @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @
6: @   @   @   @   @   @   @   Z   Z   @
7: @   Z   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @
8: @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @
9: Z   @   @   @   Z   @   @   @   @   z
```

Character `z` will be the one I wish to compare whether located at the same column same row or not.

Is there any possibility I do not require to check one by one when I am comparing both maps?

Comment: Does case matter? That is, are you concerned only about the lower-case "z" as you indicated "Character z will be the one...", or was that a typo in the question (and in the tables, where some are lower-case and some are upper-case)?

Comment: @DavidZemens , is not case sensitive.

Comment: @pnuts yes,you are right. I wish to know whether the position "z" in sheet 1 is same with the position "z" in sheet 2 or not.

Comment: @pnuts i meant that is not case sensitive for character "z" ...lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand, something like:

```
=Sheet1!A1=A1
```

in say L1 of Sheet2, copied across to U1 and then L1:U1 copied down to L9 should indicate where there are differences.

---

The solution presently chosen by the OP (see Comment) is not the above, though a variation of the above:

```
=IF(A1="z",Sheet1!A1=A1,"")
```

This accurately identifies which cells in Sheet2 are occupied with `z` or `Z` that, for the same position are not occupied by `z` or `Z` in Sheet1 (ie A3 and J9).

For the example this happens to identify all the differences because Sheet2 is effectively a copy of Sheet1 except that two `z`s in Sheet2 replace two `@`s in Sheet1.

This may be all OP wants but does not cover identification that, for example, the E4 cells are different. If “present in Sheet1 and not present in Sheet2” is of interest it could be addressed either by repeating the formula above in Sheet1 (with change of Sheet1 to Sheet2):

```
=IF(A1="z",Sheet2!A1=A1,"")
```

to detect differences in E4, B5 and G8, or, if just to display in a single sheet (say Sheet2) a slightly more elaborate formula such as:

```
=IF(AND(A1="z",Sheet1!A1="z"),"-",IF(AND(A1="z",Sheet1!A1<>"z"),2,IF(AND(A1<>"z",Sheet1!A1="z"),1,"")))
```

for a result of this kind:

[image: SO23945826 example]

where:

blanks = no `z` or `Z` in that position on either sheet
hyphen = `z` or `Z` in that position on both sheets
`1` = `z` or `Z` on Sheet1 and not on Sheet2
`2` = `z` or `Z` on Sheet2 and not on Sheet1

Comment: Should work. OP wants something that doesn't require checking *all* of the cells. Could be done with range `.Find` method in each map, and then compare the `.Address` of each...  but this seems a lot easier, unless it's something that he's doing very frequently, I'd stick with the formula.

Comment: Ehhhh now that I re-read the question I think OP needs to clarify. I read it initially as only looking for a lower-case "z", but now that I look again, there is no such character in the first table and I think it is asking for more of what you describe.  Your solution is what I would use.

Comment: Hi, the maps I show is just a few character only, actually I have many character, is there any possible I just wan to compare only the position z is the same with another graph?

Comment: Hi guys, I think I found my solution, I have modify my formula become =IF(A1="z",Sheet1!A1=A1,"")